# Create n variables in a for loop

Tags: python

So my task here is to calculate the euclidean distance then add it up in the following order :

Exemple: euc(AB) + euc(BC) + euc(CD)

This is how I've solve it :

```
import math
def distance_points(t1 = [], t2 = []) :
    euc_distance = math.sqrt( (t1[0]-t2[0])**2 + (t1[1]-t2[1])**2 )
    return euc_distance

def longueur(*points):
    coordonates = []
    for x in points:
       coordonates += x

    vectorA = [coordonates[0], coordonates[1]]
    vectorB = [coordonates[2], coordonates[3]]
    vectorC = [coordonates[4], coordonates[5]]
    vectorD = [coordonates[6], coordonates[7]]

    res = distance_points(vectorA, vectorB) + distance_points(vectorB, vectorC) + distance_points(vectorC, vectorD)



    return res

print(longueur((0.5, 1.0), (2.0, 1.0), (2.5, -0.5), (-1.5, -1.0)))
```

My questions is: How exactly can I implement this to work with any number of coordinates not just exactly 4 .
I specify that my `def longueur(*points):` and the way this functions is called must stayed the same (using a number of tuples).

I already spent 2 hours in python documentation but I admit I don't really know what to look for

Comment: The solution is to use a `list` of vectors instead of creating separate variables for each vector.

Comment: You should avoid using mutable objects as default arguments for functions. They can change sometimes without you knowing (https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments). In your case, this happens in the `distance_points` definition. Instead, you can (as the article suggests) set the default to `None`, and then have a check right away. `t1 = [] if t1 is None else t1` is a nice one-liner to get this done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need for all the `vectorX` variables. Just loop through the `points` list.

```
def longeur(*points):
    res = 0
    for i in range(len(points)-1):
        res += distance_points(points[i], points[i+1])
    return res
```

Comment: Indeed it's way more simple..stupid of me for not thinking about it earlier. Thank you !